# Skip few identity values when inserting into table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert SQL Server IDENTITY values into a table A. But I want to skip few values from inserting INTO table A based on table B values. i.e If Table B has values ( 1, 34 , 100 ) THEN table A should not insert these values and go to next available value. Is that possible? If so can you please help me out on this?

Comment: Please show us the table structures and some sample data and explain which values you want to skip when inserting ....

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the data is currently in table_c, then:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (w, x, y, z, val)
SELECT c.w, c.x, c.y, c.z, c.val
FROM table_c c
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.val = c.val
WHERE b.val IS NULL
```